# Creating a cross-sectional dataframe from a time series in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose we have a time series indexed by the minute as follows:

df =

```
Time (HH:MM)     Value
01/01/2014 00:00  1 
01/01/2014 00:01  2
01/01/2014 00:02  3
01/01/2014 00:03  4
...
01/08/2014 00:00  5000
...
```

I am looking to "group" the dataset by weeks, as follows:

df2 =

```
Week  Val1 Val2 Val3 Val4 ...
1     1    2    3    4    ...
2     5000 ...
3
4
...
```

In other words, each 1-minute observation in Week 1 (01/01/2014-01/08/2014) is represented as a column in df2. (There should be 10,080 minutes/columns per week).

I've tried a few functions including groupby() but most of them seem to aggregate the data, rather than splitting it into the individual columns I am looking for.

edit: It doesn't necessarily have to be in a dataframe format, but I am using this for a function where the input is weeks. Similar to trying to create a histogram of the values for *each week*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`weekofyear`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.weekofyear.html) + [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for count them for new columns names and then reshape by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

**1**. Solutions if `df` is `DataFrame` and `Time (HH:MM)` is column:

```
print (type(df))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

print (df.columns)
Index(['Time (HH:MM)', 'Value'], dtype='object')

weeks = pd.to_datetime(df['Time (HH:MM)']).dt.weekofyear.rename('Week')
countweeks = df.groupby(weeks).cumcount() + 1
df = df.set_index([weeks, countweeks])['Value'].unstack().add_prefix('Val')
print (df)
        Val1  Val2  Val3  Val4
Week                          
1        1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
2     5000.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Another solution with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html):

```
weeks = pd.to_datetime(df['Time (HH:MM)']).dt.weekofyear.rename('Week')
countweeks = df.groupby(weeks).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).radd('Val')
df = pd.pivot(index=weeks, columns=countweeks, values=df['Value']).fi
print (df)
        Val1  Val2  Val3  Val4
Week                          
1        1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
2     5000.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

---

If need replace NaNs by `0` add parameter `fill_value=0` to `unstack`:

```
weeks = pd.to_datetime(df['Time (HH:MM)']).dt.weekofyear.rename('Week')
countweeks = df.groupby(weeks).cumcount() + 1
df = df.set_index([weeks, countweeks])['Value'].unstack(fill_value=0).add_prefix('Val')
print (df)
      Val1  Val2  Val3  Val4
Week                        
1        1     2     3     4
2     5000     0     0     0
```

And in second solution use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
weeks = pd.to_datetime(df['Time (HH:MM)']).dt.weekofyear.rename('Week')
countweeks = df.groupby(weeks).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).radd('Val')
df = pd.pivot(index=weeks, columns=countweeks, values=df['Value']).fillna(0)
print (df)
        Val1  Val2  Val3  Val4
Week                          
1        1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
2     5000.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

**2**. Solutions if `s` is `Series` and `Time (HH:MM)` is index:

```
print (s)

Time (HH:MM)
01/01/2014 00:00       1
01/01/2014 00:01       2
01/01/2014 00:02       3
01/01/2014 00:03       4
01/08/2014 00:00    5000
Name: Value, dtype: int64

print (type(s))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print (s.index)
Index(['01/01/2014 00:00', '01/01/2014 00:01', '01/01/2014 00:02',
       '01/01/2014 00:03', '01/08/2014 00:00'],
      dtype='object', name='Time (HH:MM)')

weeks = pd.to_datetime(s.index).weekofyear.rename('Week')
countweeks = s.groupby(weeks).cumcount() + 1
df = s.to_frame().set_index([weeks, countweeks])['Value'].unstack().add_prefix('Val')
print (df)
        Val1  Val2  Val3  Val4
Week                          
1        1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
2     5000.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

And second solution:

```
weeks = pd.to_datetime(s.index).weekofyear.rename('Week')
countweeks = s.groupby(weeks).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).radd('Val')
df = pd.pivot(index=weeks, columns=countweeks, values=s)
print (df)
        Val1  Val2  Val3  Val4
Week                          
1        1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
2     5000.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

**3**. Solutions if `df` is `DataFrame` and `Time (HH:MM)` is index:

```
print (df)
                  Value
Time (HH:MM)           
01/01/2014 00:00      1
01/01/2014 00:01      2
01/01/2014 00:02      3
01/01/2014 00:03      4
01/08/2014 00:00   5000

print (type(df))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

print (df.index)
Index(['01/01/2014 00:00', '01/01/2014 00:01', '01/01/2014 00:02',
       '01/01/2014 00:03', '01/08/2014 00:00'],
      dtype='object', name='Time (HH:MM)')

weeks = pd.to_datetime(df.index).weekofyear.rename('Week')
countweeks = df.groupby(weeks).cumcount() + 1
df = df.set_index([weeks, countweeks])['Value'].unstack().add_prefix('Val')
```

---

```
weeks = pd.to_datetime(df.index).weekofyear.rename('Week')
countweeks = df.groupby(weeks).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).radd('Val')
df = pd.pivot(index=weeks, columns=countweeks, values=df['Value'])
print (df)

        Val1  Val2  Val3  Val4
Week                          
1        1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
2     5000.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: One problem I'm running into is that df is actually not a dataframe (will edit OP) but a time series indexed by time. so the first part `df['Time (HH:MM)'] ` gives me a KeyError

Comment: I think simpliest is call first `df = df.reset_index(name='Time (HH:MM)')`

Comment: @Adam - I add solutions for `input Series`

Comment: Both seem like reasonable answers, but I can't seem to get past this error.

I called that, and it spat out:
`ValueError: cannot insert Time (HH:MM), already exists`

If I were to call something like `print(df['Time (HH:MM)'])`
Then I get `KeyError: 'Time (HH:MM)'`

Comment: I think if input is Series, I a bit modify answers - see last 2 paragraphs.

Comment: But if input is `DataFrame` with `timeindex` - `df = df.rename_axis('Week').reset_index()`

Comment: No more errors! However the output spits out `[53 rows x 40320 columns]`. Based on the data I have, I should theoretically have roughly 232 x 10080.

(Since there are 10,080 minutes in a week and I have 232 weeks)

Comment: I think it is data relate problem - My solution working nice if each row of input data is unique minute time like in your sample. But if get different output it seems input time data are different. I add solution for check it, give me a minute

Comment: You can  check it by `print (df.index[pd.to_datetime(df.index).duplicated(keep=False)])` if not duplicate datetime.

Comment: Gives me `DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq='T')`

Comment: So no dupes, it is good. Hmmm, there is multiple years? Because solution working if only one year - `2014`.

Comment: Ah yes that might be it. It goes from 2014 to 2017.

Comment: Exactly. Give em a sec. What solution use with your data? 1,2.or 3.?

Comment: I think the simpliest is use `weeks = pd.to_datetime(df['Time (HH:MM)']).dt.strftime('%Y-%V').rename('Week')` - convert data to Year-Week string

Comment: I'm using your second solution part 2, as it is a Series (first one spits out an error for me)

Comment: Then use `weeks = pd.to_datetime(s.index).strftime('%Y-%V').rename('Week')`

Comment: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rename'`

Maybe there's something wrong with my data format?

Comment: You are right, `weeks = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(s.index).strftime('%Y-%V'), name='week', index=s.index)`

Comment: Very close! `[188 rows x 10080 columns]`

Columns are working, but weeks are a little weird.
`2017-24  2537.41000  
2017-25  2522.21000  
2017-26  2493.06300  
2017-27  2507.79900  
2017-28  1968.35000 `

Comment: It depends of data, hard to answer ... :(

Comment: Thank you though! I will tinker around with it

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pivot_table` like

```
In [3192]: df['Week'] = df['Time (HH:MM)'].dt.weekofyear

In [3193]: df['ValCount'] = 'Val' + df.groupby('Week').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)

In [3194]: df.pivot_table(index='Week', columns='ValCount', values='Value').reset_index()
Out[3194]:
ValCount  Week    Val1  Val2  Val3  Val4
0            1     1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
1            2  5000.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

To have `Week` in index

```
In [3198]: df.pivot_table(index='Week', columns='ValCount',
                          values='Value').rename_axis(None, 1)
Out[3198]:
        Val1  Val2  Val3  Val4
Week
1        1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
2     5000.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

---

Details

```
In [3202]: df
Out[3202]:
         Time (HH:MM)  Value
0 2014-01-01 00:00:00      1
1 2014-01-01 00:01:00      2
2 2014-01-01 00:02:00      3
3 2014-01-01 00:03:00      4
4 2014-01-08 00:00:00   5000

In [3203]: df.dtypes
Out[3203]:
Time (HH:MM)    datetime64[ns]
Value                    int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Why pivot_table? It aggregate values - not necessary here